# What to bid in this situation (xx-Kx-AQTxx-AQxx, 1D-1S-2C-2D...)? (System: Simple SAYC)

Tags: bridge, bidding

I open 1D -- Partner 1S -- I bid 2C (my holding was xx-Kx-AQTxx-AQxx) -- Partner bids 2D --
What do I bid, and why? (since I have to respond when partner keeps changing suit and no NT has been yet bid)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your partner's 2D bid was a "sign-off" bid, because it mentioned your diamonds for a second time (between the two of you), without raising to 3D, thereby allowing you to pass.

Comment: @Aryabhata: I just deleted the second sentence, since I confused myself and others. Will you reverse the downvote?

Comment: Ah. That was a carelessness on my side... somehow I remembered "keeps changing suits" instead of "keeps bidding unbid previously suits" - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your 2C was nonforcing; partner could have passed 2C but instead showed a preference for your first suit with 2D. This is to play. Depending on your responding style, partner could have as little as

```
KTxxx
xxxx
xx
xx
```

or as much as

```
KQxx
Qxx
Jxx
xxx
```

In any case, you don't have quite enough to take another bid and should pass. To bid again, you should have at least reversing strength (e.g.

```
Kx
Kx
AQTxx
AQxx
```

which in my opinion is not quite enough to make a game-forcing jump-shift after partner responds).

Comment: On your last example, open 1D, then jump to 2NT after partner bids 1 of a major.

Comment: @woodchips That's a reasonable treatment, though not universal.

Comment: @woodchips: FYI: An opening bid poll for this on bridgewinners: http://bridgewinners.com/article/view/bidding-problem-2690/ .You might need to register and vote to see the results. As of now 1D has 22, while 1NT has 12.